# Error when installing windows installer 4.5 - You do not have permission to update Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I'm trying to install window installer 4.5 but i'm getting an error reading "You do not have permission to update Windows XP. Please contact your system administrator". See short screencast to see issue.

http://screenr.com/zAn

I'm a domain admin and local admin and still can't get this to install. I can install applications but i'm guessing the issue is to do with update the XP OS.

If you need any more information please feel free to comment.

thanks!

note: this issue has been touch upon on superuser.com - https://superuser.com/questions/142993/why-am-i-getting-permission-denied-installing-powershell-2-0-on-windows-xp-and-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a GPO being applied to it?

What if you move the computer to the "computers" container (no GPOs there) and bounce the machine (or gpupdate /force).  At least then you can rule the policies out.

Guessing you saw these:

Generic:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951244

More Specific:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqltools/thread/dfdb0236-1d9c-41a0-899b-6f1a3abcbae1

Comment: Not sure where the issue was but after a few GP updates and tweeks and a few odd reboots i managed to get Windows Installer updated.